# Android Wifip2p: Why is group info null after connecting to group owner

Tags: android, sockets, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am trying to connect multiple devices to a group owner that I select manually

I want the peers to connect to the group owner manually once they find him

I have 3 phones (no emulators), on each there is a "Create group" button with this click handler

```
public void createWifiGroup(View view) {

    mManager.createGroup(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

            mManager.requestGroupInfo(mChannel,new MyGroupInfoListener(MainActivity.this));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {

        }
    });

}
```

As you can see I do `requestGroupInfo` and pass it a listener that is printing the following line in logs:

```
groupFormed: true isGroupOwner: true groupOwnerAddress: /192.168.49.1
```

So I suppose it succeeded

I also have a `MyPeerListener` class that the `BroadCastReceiver` calls when a `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` action intent is received.

`MyPeerListener` will iterate through the peers and connect if it finds a group owner

```
 @Override
    public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList wifiP2pDeviceList) {
        this.wifiP2pDeviceList = wifiP2pDeviceList;
        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(receiver.mActivity, "I found some peers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        // toast.show();
        Iterator<WifiP2pDevice> deviceListIterator = wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList().iterator();
        boolean foundGroup = false;
        while (deviceListIterator.hasNext()) {
            final WifiP2pDevice device = deviceListIterator.next();
            if (!foundGroup && device.isGroupOwner() && !MainActivity.connected) {

                //MainActivity.mManager.removeGroup(MainActivity.mChannel, null);

                foundGroup = true;

                final WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                //config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
                config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
                config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;

                MainActivity.mManager.connect(MainActivity.mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        //success logic
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(receiver.mActivity, "connect success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        MainActivity.connected = true;
                        MainActivity.mManager.requestGroupInfo(MainActivity.mChannel, new MyGroupInfoListener(receiver.mActivity));
                        MainActivity.mManager.requestConnectionInfo(MainActivity.mChannel, new MyConnectionInfoListener(receiver));


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        //failure logic
                        //MainActivity.connected = false;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(receiver.mActivity, "connect fail, reason: " + reason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                    }

                });
            }
            ListView list = (ListView) receiver.mActivity.findViewById(R.id.device_list_view);
            list.setAdapter(new DeviceListViewAdapter(this, receiver.mActivity));
        }

        }


    }
```

(I am aware of the use of static variables and overall bad design , but this is a fast prototype to learn)

Now I get a `connect success` `Toast` but the `requestConnectionInfo` right after the connection shows me this line

```
groupFormed: false isGroupOwner: false groupOwnerAddress: null
```

A call to requestGroupInfo also shows:

```
group is null
```

This happens very often about 80% of the times. Sometimes it shows the default group IP `192.168.49.1` . But I'll be lucky if both the "slave" phones have correct group info.

When I try to connect a socket to the owner while the group info is null it fails with `destination host unreachable`. But when the group info is correct I can connect and send data properly.

So why is this happening ? How is it even possible that the connection succeeds but the group is null ?

Comment: There are a lot of strange issues with Wi-Fi Direct. I worked with it for a while and made a list of resources and issues that you may find helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wi-fi-direct

Comment: @Brendan indeed, it seems pretty inconsistent at times

Comment: I have found that it works best when connecting similar devices, and with little network activity nearby. You may also find this Wi-Fi Direct handler library useful if you're learning: https://github.com/Crash-Test-Buddies/WiFi-Buddy It logs a lot of information, and you can look at the source and see how it manages group connections

Answer (score 3):

I re-did the whole project and found only one mistake

I was doing

```
mManager.connect(...,new ActionListener(){
@Override
onSuccess(){
    //Here I called requestConnectionInfo right after the pairing happens
    mManager.requestConnectionInfo(myConnectionInfoListener);
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    // try to connect and send data....

}

@Override
onFailure(int reason){

}

});
```

So I removed the `requestConnectionInfo()` from inside of `onSuccess()` callback of `connect()` and out it in `MyWifiDirectBroadcastReceiver` that extends `BroadcastReceiver`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        //Here is where the request for connection info should happen
        //As sometimes the pairing can happen but the devices 
        //might still be negotiating group owner for example
        mManager.requestConnectionInfo(myConnectionInfoListener());
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
    }
}
```

`MyConnectionInfoListener` never return null info after this change, and I connect to the IP provided by the listener without any problems.